# Does /usr/bin/perl run as separate processes when invoked with one script multiple times?

Tags: database, multithreading, perl, scheduler

It's a web server scenario. Linux is the OS. Different IP Addresses call the same script.

Does Linux start a new process of Perl for every script call or does Perl run the multiple calls interleaved or do the scripts run serially (one after another)?

Sorry, I didn't find an answer within the first few results of Google.

I need to know in order to know how much I have to worry about concurrent database access.

The script itself is NOT using multiple threads, it's a straightforward Perl script.

Update: more sophisticated scheduler or serialiser of comment to answer below, still untested:

```
#! usr/bin/perl

use Fcntl;
use Time::HiRes;


sysopen(INDICATOR, "indicator", O_RDWR | O_APPEND); # filename hardcoded, must exist
flock(INDICATOR, LOCK_EX);
print INDICATOR $$."\n";    # print a value unique to this script
                            # in single-process context it's serial anyway
                            # in multi-process context the pid is unique
seek(INDICATOR,0,0);
my $firstline = <INDICATOR>;
close(INDICATOR);

while("$firstline" ne $$."\n")
{
    nanosleep(1000000);     # time your script to find a better value
    open(INDICATOR, "<", "indicator");
    $firstline = <INDICATOR>;
    close(INDICATOR);
}

do "transferHandler.pl";    # name of your script to run

sysopen(INDICATOR, "indicator", O_RDWR);
flock(INDICATOR, LOCK_EX);
my @content = <INDICATOR>;
shift @content;
truncate(INDICATOR,0);
seek(INDICATOR,0,0);
foreach $line(@content)
{
    print INDICATOR $line;
}
close(INDICATOR);
```

Edit again: above script would not work if perl runs in a single process and threads (interleaves) scripts itself. Such a scenario is the only one of the 3 asked by me which appears not to be the case based on the answer and feedback I got verbally separately. Above script can be made to work then by changing the unique value to a random number rather than the pid on quick thought however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely depended on set up of your web server. Does it uses plain CGI, FastCGI, mod_perl? You can set up both of scenarios you've described. In case of FastCGI you can also set up for a script to never exit, but do all its work inside a loop that keeps accepting connections from frontend web server.

Regarding an update to your question, I suggest you to start worrying about concurrent access from very start. Unless you're doing some absolutely personal application and deliberately set up your server to strictly run one copy of your script, pretty much any other site will sometime grow into something that will require 2 or more parallel processing scripts. You will save yourself a lot of headache if you plan this very common task ahead. Even if you only have one serving script, you will need indexing/clean up/whatever done by offline tasks and this will mean concurrent access once again.

Comment: FastCGI is installed. Do you have a link to a description of how to set up FCGI regarding the topic? It's not supposed to be a high-demand application. If Linux would schedule multiple invocations of the script in case it's necessary I would be happy. Or can I create a scheduler script myself? After all n*serially or n parallel should be equal in time consumption even if some have to wait longer. But it's a small script.

Comment: There's a good example right in module documentation synopsis: http://search.cpan.org/~flora/FCGI-0.74/FCGI.PL

Comment: I couldn't make much of that synopsis actually: e.g. does accept() wait or return immediately? (I guess it waits.) I'll try to create a schedule script on create-file-as-already-executing-indicator with a sleep if file exists to prevent concurrent execution. If it doesn't execute concurrently to begin with, that script would also work. As your answer makes it seem it's Apache dependent, I'll try to find the relevant docs to set up concurrency or not. I'll be grateful for pointers to such docs still too.

Comment: accept() waits for incoming connection. While loop executes, all pending connections are handled by FCGI and stay in queue until script accepts again. You can set up Apache (or any server for that matter) to either maintain one copy of script or several. Each freed up script will pick up new connection from queue in FIFO order.

Comment: Thanks, that would do it. Nevertheless, here's an untested scheduler: argument 0 = perl script to run, arg. 1 = filename as indicator, arg. 2 = number nanoseconds to wait until try again to execute. I guess if 2 calls interleave through the check by the while, they had to come at around nearly equal cpu instruction counter values or similar. Unlikely for the projected audience.

`#! usr/bin/perl

use Time::HiRes;

while(-e $ARGV[1])
{
 nanosleep($ARGV[2]);
}

open INDICATOR, ">", $ARGV[1];
close INDICATOR;
do $ARGV[0];
unlink $ARGV[1];`

Answer (score 0):

If the perl scripts as invoked separately they will result in separate processes. Here is an demo using two scripts:

```
#master.pl
system('perl ./sleep.pl &');
system('perl ./sleep.pl &');
system('perl ./sleep.pl &');

#sleep.pl
sleep(10);
```

Then run:

```
perl tmp.pl & (sleep 1 && ps -A | grep perl)
```

Comment: I can't comment on the question itself, but it asks whether multiple invokations of the perl binary cause a corresponding new processes to be created, not whether it's possible to create a script that can handle multiple or simultaneous requests.